# Iterating in some positions of a vector python

Tags: python, vector

I am iterating in a vector, but I need to iterate only in even positions:

```
c = ([coord[0], coord[1])
a = coord[0]
b = coord[1]

for x,y in zip(a,b): 
    rectObs.append(pygame.Rect((y,x),(10,10)))

for rect in rectObs:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, rect,10)
```

This code draws all the positions, but I need only even positions, for 
example:

```
a = coord[0] = [4(pos0), 8(pos1), 1(pos2), 10(pos3), 7(pos4), 5(pos5)]
b = coord[1] = [5(pos0), 2(pos1), 7(pos2), 6(pos3), 1(pos4), 11(pos5)]
```

I need draw in the vector `"a"` only `[4, 1, 7]` and in the vector `"b"` `[5, 7, 1]`

Comment: What is a "vector"? What is `coord`? Please provide some sort of self-contained example.

Comment: Please give us working code, the first line of this has a syntax error. And you haven't told anybody what `coord` is. Include a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
vec = list(zip(a,b))
for i in range(0,len(vec),2):
    x,y = vec[i]
    ...
```

Also:

```
for x,y in list(zip(a,b))[::2]:
    ...
```